# how do I insert audio x seconds into a video?

Tags: audio

How can I insert audio x seconds into a video?

Suppose it's an mp3 audio file with an mp4 or avi video?

Different solutions are welcome.

Comment: Do you have any existing encoding/transcoding/multiplexing software currently installed? Are you looking to do it via command line or is a GUI non-linear editor an option?

Comment: @Uninspired I like the command line. I have ffmpeg and avidemux, i'm interested in others.. I have videodub.  I am not that fmailiar with them.  I don't know how to do it in them.  Whatever solutions you know of.. the more the better though don't put too much of your time into it! but deserving of +++ for more.

Comment: @Uninspired  What tools do you know that you think are good at doing it?

Comment: xilisoft might have software that can and their pricing is very reasonable and their software is small and perfect for particular video editing tasks.  Adobe Premiere Pro(big video editting package) can do it but the pricing is extreme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avidemux is able to use external audio track from MP3, AC3 or WAV. Just open your video, select *Copy* for *Video* in the left settings tab and then go to main menu *Audio/Main track* and you will get dialog *Main audio track* and choose for *Audio: External MP3* instead of default setting *Video*. Then simply save your video.

This solution has one limitation (as I know) - the new audio replaces your original audio track and always starts with the video. So if you need to combine your MP3 with the video sound, then save your audio track from Avidemux, use Audacity to cut and combine it with your MP3 files and finally import it back to video using Avidemux again.

added by barlop
{
looks like you're saying, to extract the audio from the video with avidemux, import the audio into Audacity, and in Audacity, use features like cut/paste/join, to add your audio clip into the desired position within the audio you imported, e.g. you want to insert audio at 12 seconds so cut after 12 seconds of the imported audio, add your audio clip in then paste what you cut to be after that. So if the original was 10 minutes, and the inserted clip you put in e.g. in the middle of it e.g. whatever seconds in but say it was 10 seconds in length, you now have an audio in there that is 10 minutes 10 seconds.  Save that new audio still in audacity, then tell avidemux to use that external audio instead of the original one.
}

If you prefer more user friendly approach, then use some more advanced editor - maybe Pinnacle Studio (have to pay for it, and it needs to recompress your video before saving) or on linux something like Kdenlive, Open Movie Editor etc. (these are free and have similar use as Pinnacle).

good luck :-)

Comment: i'm not on linux. but anyhow.. , How do you make the audio x seconds in?  you say "then save your audio track from Avidemux, use Audacity to cut and combine it with your MP3 files and finally import it back to video using Avidemux again." so you  are saying extract the audio with avidemux.  but then how do I put it x seconds into the video?

Comment: oh, I see what you're saying.. but cutting it then doing that then joining it,it's a bit open to issues and i'd rather have a tool that can do it in one.

Comment: could be your suggestion is normal way..

Comment: Ok, then use Pinnacle Studio or the free Pinnacle VideoSpin. During the 14days trial period (only for mpeg2/4 import/export filters) you would be able to solve your task relatively easily. But as I say, you will have to re-encode the video to get AVI or MP4 again.

Answer (score 0):

Use MKVToolNix, it's an opensource tool supporting Linux, MacOSX and Windows, and it allows to insert an audio with a delay (right pane, scroll to the bottom part). It does not require re-encoding the files, so it is pretty fast and produces as small files as the addition of the input files.